# What does 5d4 x 10 gp mean?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, wealth

What does 5d4 x 10 gp mean?

I’m creating an Eladrin Ranger/Bard and I’m trying to figure out my starting wealth.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 35):

It means that if you are creating a Ranger or Bard, if you choose not to take the standard equipment packages from your Class and Background, you instead roll five four-sided dice (5d4), add them together, then multiply the result by 10 to determine the number of gold pieces you start with, which you then use to buy your equipment during character creation.

Note that this is not allowed in Adventurer's League play, to ensure fairness between all players; instead, you *must* choose your standard equipment packages from your Class and Background.

Comment: Ok, I was confused and thought you got that on top of your starting equipment. Thank you!

Comment: Does AL specifically call out balance reasons for having to select the equipment? I always did find starting gold differing by class to be a strange thing

Comment: @SeriousBri I believe the motivation is not so much that different classes have different starting gold (that can be compensated by other low-level advantages and disadvantages) but rather the randomness of it. A single bad roll before the game even started can greatly affect the session 1 survival chance of every new character.

Comment: @SeriousBri Also, a big part I've seen of different classes having different amounts of starting gold is rooted in the fact that different classes have a more-or-less expensive start-up cost. A monk can show up to a party with 7sp worth of gear (common clothes and a quarterstaff) and be a perfectly functional combatant. A Fighter? Not so much...armor and good weapons are expensive. And a Wizard without that 50gp spellbook and a (minimum) 5gp focus is kinda helpless. So if everyone started with the same amount of gold...Monks would all enter play ludicrously rich.

Comment: Thanks both, makes a bit more sense now!

Comment: @user56410 Please consider selecting this as the correct answer if you believe it is so.

Answer (score 5):

Roll five 4-sided dice. Then multiply the result by 10. That is your starting wealth.